# Is LifecycleService deprecated along with lifecycle-extensions artifact?

Tags: android, deprecated, androidx, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle

It seems the LifecycleService class that used to live in the `lifecycle-extensions` artifact is not available in any of the current recommended artifacts. I'd expect it to be in `lifecycle-runtime`, which is the one without ViewModel andLiveData, but `LifecycleService` is not in `lifecycle-viewmodel` or `lifecycle-livedata`.

Has LifecycleService been deprecated?

[Source on current Lifecycle artifacts](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#declaring_dependencies)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `LifecycleService` is in the `lifecycle-service` dependency as per the [Lifecycle 2.2.0 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.2.0):

> `lifecycle-extensions` Artifact Deprecation: With the above deprecation of `ViewModelProviders.of()`, this release marks the deprecation of the last API in `lifecycle-extensions` and this artifact should now be considered deprecated in its entirety. We strongly recommend depending on the specific Lifecycle artifacts you need (**such as `lifecycle-service` if you’re using `LifecycleService`** and `lifecycle-process` if you’re using `ProcessLifecycleOwner`) rather than lifecycle-extensions as there will not be a future `2.3.0` release of `lifecycle-extensions`.

Comment: Thanks, Ian, didn't see that. Should I report this as a documentation bug, or is the team aware of it already? I'd be happy to update the docs if they're open-source.

Comment: You can [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192697), but unfortunately the documentation is not open source. If you reply with the bug you've filed, I can redirect it to the right person.